# Height of elements are 0px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

Hi so I have divs in an accordion:

```
    <a href="#collapse17" data-quickedit-field-id="paragraph/17/field_section_title/en/default" class="field field--name-field-section-title field--type-string field--label-hidden accordion-toggle field--item" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">
  <h2><strong>Accordion Header</strong></h2>
</a>
<div id="collapse17" data-quickedit-field-id="paragraph/17/field_section/en/default" class="field field--name-field-section field--type-entity-reference-revisions field--label-hidden panel-collapse collapse field--item">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div data-quickedit-field-id="paragraph/10/field_diagram_title/en/default" class="field field--name-field-diagram-title field--type-string field--label-hidden p-1 section-title-diagram field--item background-purple" id="div">INDEPENDENT LEARNING12</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

when hovered over div element on inspect element, the height is 20px. But my jquery:

```
    $('.section-title-diagram').each(function(){
  var $div = $("#div");
    var height = $div.height();
  var text = $div.text();
  console.log("Height: ", height);
  console.log("Text: ", text);
});
```

is 0.
When I do

```
var text = $(this).text();
console.log(text);
```

it does spit out correctly `INDEPENDENT LEARNING12`. I am stuck on why height of my div is 0. I have tried multiple things, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/xotu9qgj/5/

Comment: Hey Armando. I don't believe you've included enough code for us to help you solve this issue. As you can see [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xotu9qgj/), the code in your question works as expected, meaning your issue is somewhere else. Please edit your question to include a [**minimal, complete, verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please show completely hover code

Comment: @TylerRoper I have updated to show all the code

Comment: @AliNaeimi updated to show all the code

Comment: It is because, your code that checking the height is running when the div is invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you set

```
.collapse {
    display: none;
}
```

in your css

change to display:block

or set `$('.collapse').show();` in your jquery code.

Comment: I want to hide my element but just get the height of it. So I wait until clicked, then setTimeout and let the element transition to show before getting it's height. But yes, if I didn't care to hide element I would display block.

Comment: set $('.collapse').show(); after click and you can get height div.

Comment: So I made it a bit better. $('.collapse').show() makes it so when you click on accordion again it will not collapse (you then have to code more). BUT, if you use $('#collapse17').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){//code}; it works perfectly for me. http://jsfiddle.net/xotu9qgj/15/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xotu9qgj/15/

```
$('#collapse17').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
var diagram_title = $(this).find('.section-title-diagram');
  $(diagram_title).each(function(){
    var $div = $("#div");
    var height = $div.height();
    var text = $div.text();
    console.log("Height: ", height);
    console.log("Text: ", text);
  });
});
```